# Python3 Stripe API to get all customer email

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments

Stripe API doesn't seem to allow us to get all the customer info in one shot. The following codes can print 1000 customers' email

```
import stripe

stripe.api_key = "secret"

customer_dict = stripe.Customer.list(limit=1000)

print(customer_dict)

for i in range(len(customer_dict)):

  print(customer_dict.data[i]['email'])
```

results:

```
abc@gmail.com
def@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com
etc.
```

But assuming I have an unlimited number of Stripe customers, how can I print all their emails?

If I used their auto_paging_iter, it will just keep printing out the 10 most recent email.

```
customer_dict = stripe.Customer.list(limit=10)

for customer in customer_dict.auto_paging_iter():

  # print(customer_dict)

  for i in range(len(customer_dict)):

    print(customer_dict.data[i]['email'])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a limit higher than 100, and auto-paging iterator is likely what you want here, but instead of what you're doing, you'll want to do this:

```
for customer in customer_dict.auto_paging_iter(limit=100):
  print(customer['email'])
```

customer_dict, as an array, only contains the initial 10 objects.  If you want to create an array of all of the emails for all of your customers, you could do something like this:

```
customer_emails = [c['email'] for c in customer_dict.auto_paging_iter(limit=100)]
```

...or similar.